# Prove that if $\Gamma \not \vdash \bot$, then there exists a valuation such that $[[\psi]] = 1$ for all $\psi \in \Gamma$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I tried to prove by the contrapositive of the implication, that is:

1. if there's a $\psi \in \Gamma$ such that $[[\psi]] \not = 1$ for every valuation, then $\Gamma \vdash \bot$.
2. I know that $v(\bot) = 0$ for every v. Then $\psi$ such that $[[\psi]] \not = 1$ for every valuation must be equivalent to $\bot$.
3. Then we can conclude that $\bot \in \Gamma$. Hence, $\Gamma \vdash \bot$.

But I'm not quite sure if step 3 is formally correct since I couldn't find "if $\psi \in \Gamma \rightarrow \Gamma \vdash \psi$ in my textbook even though I know it is intuitively correct

Comment: Part 1 doesn't seem right: the negation of the conclusion would be that for each valuation, there exists $\psi \in \Gamma$ such that $[[\psi]] \ne 1$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler sorry, I can't tell the difference. What you said looks exactly the same as step 1.

Comment: Different order of quantifiers: yours has $(\exists \psi \in \Gamma) (\forall v \in V) [[\psi]]_v \ne 1$ where $V$ is the set/class of valuations, mine has $(\forall v \in V) (\exists \psi \in \Gamma) [[\psi]]_v \ne 1$.  You need to allow which $\psi$ is not satisfied to vary depending on the valuation.

Comment: @DanielSchepler thanks for noting that, but isn't the result the same in this case?

Comment: $\vdash$ is *derivability* i.e. about axioms and rules. In order to prove $\Gamma \vdash \bot$ you have to use somewhere the proof system.